# GET request 'find by name' instead of find by id

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a way for me use this code or a similar code to find by username instead of findById?

```
Router.route('/:id').get(function (req, res)
 {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Books.findById(id, function (err, course) {
        res.json(course);
    });
});
```

Comment: Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_query.asp

Comment: Given that code, no, it's not possible. You should check if the `Books` object has a method like .findByUserName or similar

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Books is a model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Books.find({username: 'username'},function (err, course) {res.json(course);});
```

or

```
Books.find({username: /username/i},function (err, course) {res.json(course);}); // Like operator
```

I hope it works
Look at [Mongoose Docs here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Comment: Warning: .find() will return an array of documents even if there is only one document that matches the filters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing called find by name. You can use find or findOne instead.

```
Books.find({username: 'username',function (err, course) {
    res.json(course);
});

Books.findOne({username: 'username',function (err, course) {
    res.json(course);
});
```

With Regex Pattern

```
Books.findOne({username: 'username'/gi,function (err, course) {
    res.json(course);
});
```

Comment: Warning: .find() will return an array of documents even if there is only one document that matches the filters.

Comment: @VirgilioGM  that is why I mentioned findOne as well

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, of course, but IMHO the variable course suggests that it contains a single document and so I thought it appropriate to warn, in case the OP had doubts about it. Perhaps it would be more clear if the variable returned by the .find() function was courses.